# Assign degree of belief according to the evidence code that support the Go annotation

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I want to assign some degree of belief that how the [Go annotation](http://geneontology.org/page/annotation) to a particular term is supported which is represented by evidence code. 
There are different type of [evidence codes](http://geneontology.org/page/guide-go-evidence-codes):

1. Experimental Evidence codes (IDA,IEP,IGI,IMI, IPI)
2. Author Statement evidence codes (NAS,TAS)
3. Curatorial Statement codes (IC,ND)
4. Computational Analysis evidence codes (ISS, RCA)

How do i give the degree of belief value to one evidence code compare to others? For example: what will be the value of belief for IDA compare to IC and what will be the value of degree of value for IC ? and so on.

How can i assign all the degree of belief values for all the evidence codes? Is there any standard way for it?

Answer (score 0):

The '[Guide to GO Evidence Codes](http://geneontology.org/page/guide-go-evidence-codes)' states that you **shouldn't** assign any quality value based only on the evidence code:
"Evidence codes are not statements of the quality of the annotation. Within each evidence code classification, some methods produce annotations of higher confidence or greater specificity than other methods, in addition the way in which a technique has been applied or interpreted in a paper will also affect the quality of the resulting annotation. Thus evidence codes cannot be used as a measure of the quality of the annotation."